DOMContentLoaded in Vuejs
today I would like to ask everyone about the resource usage problem of HTML templates for Vuejs. I'm having a problem with DOMContentLoaded, the source js files are available using DOMContentLoaded but for Vuejs it doesn't execute the code inside so I want to ask is there a way to move the template from HTML to Vuejs to use? Are not? Can I import a file with DOMContentLoaded and use it with vuejs without deleting it? Thank you very much
I tried using common but it doesn't work

It's unknown what you ask about exactly. You saw your case and others didn't. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Use the template tag inside of your .vue files and the onMounted lifecycle.
